# Вылетает программа на С в VS и Code::Blocks

Tags: c, visual-studio, codeblocks

Составлял программу для работы с двухмерным массивом, который формируется по формуле. При запуске выдает ошибку как на картинке 1. Подумал, что ошибка в типах данных, изменил - начала вылетать даже не запустившись. При запуске с отладкой появляется сообщение на картинке 2. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

   int main()
    {

        int n = 7, i=1, j=1;
        int A[7][7];

        for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
            for(j=1; j<=n; j++){
                A[i][j] = (j - 5.7) * (2 - pow((j-3), 2)) / (j+i) + 2*i;
                printf("%d\t", A[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
      return 0;  }
}
```

Comment: Вылет за границы массива! Нужно for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отсчет массивов идет от нуля.

Вы выходите за пределы памяти, тем самым повреждая стек.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int n = 7, i=0, j=0;
    int A[7][7];

    for(i=0; i< n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = (j - 5.7) * (2 - pow((j-3), 2)) / (j+i) + 2*i;
            printf("%d\t", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(2 - pow((j-3), 2)) / (j+i)` приведёт к делению на 0 на первой итерации

Comment: Думаю это должен решать ТС что с этим делать.

Comment: так то оно так, но взяв Ваш код, TC столкнётся с данной проблемой и неизбежно последует следующий вопрос. По крайней мере, я бы явно упомянул о таком поведении в ответе.